# Get data of locked iPod Touch (6 Gen)

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, jailbreak, ipod

I have an iPod Touch 6 Gen, iOS 10.0.3, that is locked. On the display, there is a message after I startup device "iPod is locked". This is because someone tries too many attempts to unlock the iPod. I do not have any Backup from it. Now, I try to get the data.

I did try the CheckM8 Tool. This is able to remove the passcode. It ships also the Jailbreak tool Checkra1n within, to previous unlock the iPod:

https://checkm8.info/unlock-passcode-disabled-iphone-ipad

Unfortunately, when I run the tool on my Mac, it says:

"iPod touch 6 gen are supported, but iOS 10.0.3 is not"

What other possibilities do I get?

Is it possible, to get a dump of the whole disk, and brute force it?

Comment: Even if you'd had the correct iOS for checkm8, doing this will wipe all data. Apple are the only ones who can unlock a device. Take it to them with proof of purchase. This is done intentionally to prevent theft. A stolen iDevice is a brick to anyone except its legitimate owner.

Comment: @Tetsujin I never heard that before and i also found nothing in terms of ask Apple for unlock my device. I cant imagine, that Apple will do that. Why they should? They even refuse to the fbi.

Comment: If you can prove it belongs to you, they will unlock it. Take it to an Apple Store with proof of ownership.